# including header files from prebuilt library Android.mk

Tags: c++, maven, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have included a prebuilt library into my library creation using

```
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and verified weather library is included or not by using

```
$(modules-get-list)
```

When i try to include a header file present within prebuilt library, i face error header not found. Below is my exact Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# import prebuilt-library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := prebuilt-library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../target/dependency/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libprebuilt.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# building provider interface library for communication
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := library-interface
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := LibraryComminicator.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := prebuilt-library

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(warning Existing modules: "$(modules-get-list)")

# Include the Android Maven plugin generated makefile
# Important: Must be the last import in order for Android Maven Plugins paths to work
include $(ANDROID_MAVEN_PLUGIN_MAKEFILE)
```

Comment: Maybe, you should use `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../../../target/dependency/include` ?

Comment: @AlexCohn i have modified it to include header files but still same result

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Try `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../target/dependency/include`

Comment: i have actually tried that too but still same result

Comment: Can *you* find the missing header file on your disk? Or maybe you don't need this include?

Comment: i can see all header files within "target/dependency/include", but those are not included in the library creation. Is there a way to list all header files considered for build.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155787/discussion-between-rajesh-and-alex-cohn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **Android.mk** below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
EXT_LIB_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../target/dependency # or whatever

# building provider interface library for communication
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := library-interface
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := LibraryComminicator.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := prebuilt-library

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# import prebuilt-library
LOCAL_PATH := $(EXT_LIB_ROOT)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := prebuilt-library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libprebuilt.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(warning Existing modules: "$(modules-get-list)")
```

The basic rules are: xxx_INCLUDE_FILES should be relative to 'current dir', while LOCAL_SRC_FILES are relative to $(LOCAL_PATH), not to the 'current dir'. With NDK, typically the 'current dir' is `$(LOCAL_PATH)/..` but this could change, especially if **Android.mk** files are linked, i.e. one includes another.

And you really don't need LOCAL_PATH for PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY modules, but I prefer to keep LOCAL_SRC_FILES as short as possible.

Comment: `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES   := /Users/rk/native-test/apk-solution/target/dependency/libs/include/com/raj/vs/ndktest/base`

This version of c_includes works good but  fails for below one


`EXT_LIB_ROOT              := ../../../target/dependency/libs
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES   := $(EXT_LIB_ROOT)/include/com/cnh/pf/activation/base
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)`

Comment: Yes, it fails because as I explained above the 'current directory' for **ndk-build** is not exactly defined, and usually it is the project directory one level above the **Android.mk** file (which is, by convention, called **jni** and returned by `$(call my-dir)` as relative path. Therefore, your definition of EXT_LIB_ROOT should probably be `$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../target/dependency/libs`

Comment: But you can easily check by adding `$(warning LOCAL_PATH=$(LOCAL_PATH))` to your **Android.mk**